# One time 404 error for a custom index page of a subdirectory (.htaccess error?)

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, subdirectory

I have a website where the folder structure of it is something like this

```
/
-/cart
-/account
-/main
```

The root `/` folder have an index.php page but each subfolder have a custom first/index page of the same name. So `/cart` have a `cart.php` page, `/main` have a `main.php` page, etc.

Each folder (including the root) have a `.htaccess` that look similar to this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

DirectoryIndex disabled
DirectoryIndex (INSERT FOLDER NAME).php
```

The problem is that when someone access, for example, `https://website.com/cart` it gives a 404 error for the first time. If you refresh the page, it works very well after. But the error appears each time for each different subfolder.

I have tried to add something like this for each directory in the root `.htaccess`

```
<Directory "/cart">
    DirectoryIndex disabled
    DirectoryIndex cart.php
</Directory>
```

But it just made the website stop working.

I have also searched for index stuff in the CPanel of the website but didn't find something (or maybe don't have access to a specific option because the website is on a shared-hosting).

So, now I'm kinda lost, I'm not really familiar with .htaccess file, surely something that I don't know.